# user-defined literals combined with an uint64_t argument

Tags: c++, c++14, user-defined-literals

I just stumbled into the following user-defined literal:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr auto operator""_G(uint64_t v) { return v * 1'000'000'000ULL; }
```

However, this does not compile with GNU 7.3.0 and `-std=c++14`. I get an "has invalid argument list" error.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal, the only allowed unsigned 64 bit type is `unsigned long long int`. However, the `uint64_t` typedef from `stdint.h` is mapped to to GCC built-in define `__UINT64_TYPE__`.

```
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int;
```

This definition is obtained by running `gcc -dM -E an_empty_file.c | grep "__UINT64_TYPE__"`

Of course, replacing the `uint64_t` with an `unsigned long long int` avoids the compile error. But the two types are identical on the LP64 data model.

Shouldn't this work by default?

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint64_t, unsigned long long>);` triggers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't this work by default?

Nope.  That standard mandates that the type of the user defined literal be `unsigned long long int`<sup>[[1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.literal#lex.ext-3)</sup>.  A `long unsigned int` is not the same thing, it is its own distinct type.  Even if they have the exact same properties, `std::is_same_v<unsigned long long int, long unsigned int>` is false.

You must use a type that is `unsigned long long int` if you want to take an integer number for your literal.